# node js rest api with exclusive access

Tags: node.js, api, rest, authentication

I have to implement an api rest with nodejs.
As I need a sort of session, I was thinking to use the basic http api (we are under https).

The problem is that one of the requirements is that if an user already logged do the login from from another browse , his previous session should be logged out.

What's the best approch to solve this? There are some library for nodejs I can use to do it quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have do that manually because sessionstore only stores client with their their respective cookies if you want to there should be no two cookies for same client i.e client should not be logged in from two different places than you have to write that logic by yourself i.e iterate over the sessionstore and expire the cookie if there are two cookies with same user.

Comment: I would like to avoid to use the cookie.
My idea were to create a custom token after the login, and pass this token as header on every call witch need the authentication.
This is why until now I've just used the basic http auth, maybe with other authentication I can have this for free

Comment: Are u using jwt token?

Comment: btw thanks, jwt seems exactly what I need.
I can have an initial login and then use the jwt token to keep track of the session.